# Where to put google tag manager's tag snippet in Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In app.component.html file, I have only two tags. `<nav-bar>` and `<router-outlet>` tags. To add Google Tag Manager tag snippet we all know that the `<script>` tag should be inserted inside `<head>` tag of the html file and the `<noscript>` tag should be inserted inside `<body>` tag. As I don't have `<head>` and `<body>` tag in app.component.html file and they are autogenerated, where am I supposed to insert this google tag manager tag snippet?

Comment: you have a head tag in index.html... put it there. also check out angulartics2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about google tag manager but you can set it in your app.component template or you can put in the bottom of your index.html like

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [{
    'pageCategory': 'signup',
    'visitorType': 'high-value'
  }];
</script>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
...
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind it might be best to leave the dataLayer as an empty array and set properties at the component level. Otherwise if you forget to explicitly set these values they will retain their original value. Simply initializing it before your tag manager script like this will work for getting you up and running.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
```